# PHP and Keywords

Tags: php, html, keyword

I would like to know if I can make a php script that will allow me to echo keywords into a meta tag.To be more precise will the keywords echoed by the php script be indexed by search engines? I don't need the actual script I just need to know if this will be any good for indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know it won't do you any good. The search engine crawlers will *see* your meta tag, but Google, for example, ignores the keywords when determining relevance.

If you want search engine visibility you should focus on your content and presentation. Be sure to follow the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/) recommendations on publishing HTML content.

Comment: yep, correct: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html

Comment: I don't even care if I'm correct. I just want people to stop shoving keywords in their pages and focus on real content.

Comment: Well not really pointless, because the keywords tag **should** tell something about your page. The reason it is ignored is that webmasters have the habit of spamming it with keywords that don't summarize their real content.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. They will also be seen by Google crawler/bot. The reason is that PHP is server-side language, your code is generated on server and sent back to browser for people and search engines to see.

Answer (score 0):

search engines crawl web pages (actually their "robots" do). how you generate the content of the pages is not relevant. important is that you generate the content in a SEO (search engine optimization) way.

it is best to check out googles ressources on how to structure that content: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" lang="<?=$language;?>" content="<?=$keywords;?>"  />
```

The variable $keywords should contain the keywords separated with **,** for example:
**"news, php, java, perl"**